# Is there .NET equivalent to Delphi's ActionList?

Tags: .net, delphi, actionlist

We're currently using Delphi 5 and Delphi 2005 for development, and investigate of going the .NET route via Delphi Prism.

Is there a .NET equivalent to Delphi's ActionList?

For those not familiar with ActionList, it's a component that contains a collection of actions that we create, e.g. Save, Refresh, Load, etc. Each action can have a caption, image, enable/disable assign to it. After that, you can assign a button to an action, and the button will inherit the action's caption, image, etc, and if you UI has the save action available as both a menu item and a button, they can both use the same action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinForms do not have such a thing build in, but WPF does with its commands. See http://www.microsoft.com/belux/msdn/nl/community/columns/jdruyts/wpf_commandpattern.mspx

Comment: WPF's ICommand is slightly different from TActionList (lack of certain features in fact).

Answer (score 3):

You may also take a look at [Actions for .NET WinForms](http://actions.codeplex.com/). Among other things, it allows to categorize actions in a Delphi-like way, and has an option to execute and/or update them asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: [Crad's Actions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CradsActions.aspx).

That is a CodeProject page describing, and hosting the original source code. The [code link](http://www.marcodesanctis.it/images/Blog/CradsActions_src.zip) on the [original author's page](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/crad/articles/38329.aspx) is broken.

It's a shame Microsoft doesn't adopt them.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I created a fork of that project and published NuGet package for it a week ago, http://www.lextm.com/2012/04/packaging-crads-actionlist-for-net-via.html