# Delphi action list equivalent in C#

Tags: winforms, delphi, c#-3.0, actionlist

in Delphi there's action list , what's the equivalent to it in C# 3 winforms application

I searched a lot but didn't find any proper way

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489376/is-there-net-equivalent-to-delphis-actionlist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent in WinForms. This is one of the most common complaints when a Delphi developer switches to WinForms.

There are various third party options but I have no personal experience with which to make a recommendation. You could take a look at this for starters: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/actionlist.aspx